# Explaining the beveridge nelson decomposition

Tags: time-series

Can someone explain how the Beveridge-Nelson Decomposition works? So far all I know is it estimates trend cycles in non stationary time series data.

I looked at multiple journal articles and I am still confused on how it works
http://research.economics.unsw.edu.au/jmorley/bn.pdf

Comment: Shouldn't be $u_t = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \psi_j \epsilon_{t-j}$ ? I'm fine with the rest then. Nice explanation.

Comment: I like [Eric Zivot's note](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ584/notes/trendcycle.pdf) on Beveridge-Nelson decomposition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Beveridge-Nelson decomposition is a decomposition of $ARIMA(p,1,q)$ process. Such process has a unit root:

$$y_t=y_{t-1}+u_{t},$$

but $u_t$ is not a white noise process, it is an $ARMA(p,q)$ process. What Beveridge and Nelson in their original article observed is that it is possible to decompose this process into two parts:

$$y_t=\tau_t+\xi_t,$$

where $\tau_t$ is now "pure" random walk, i.e. $\tau_t=\tau_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$, where $\varepsilon_t$ is a white noise proces. The term $\xi_t$ is another stationary process. This decomposition is algebraic identity (the details below), but it can lead to interesting interpretations.

The precise statement. Let $u_t=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \psi_{j}\varepsilon_{t-j}$, where $\varepsilon_t$ is a white noise process and $\sum j|\psi_j|<\infty$. Then

$$u_1+...+u_t=\psi(1)(\varepsilon_1+...+\varepsilon_t)+\eta_t-\eta_0,$$

where

$$\psi(1)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\psi_j,\quad  \eta_t=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\alpha_j\varepsilon_{t-j},\quad \alpha_j=-(\psi_{j+1}+\psi_{j+2}+...), \quad \sum|\alpha_j|<\infty.$$

This decomposition has nice application, for example

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}\sum_{t=1}^Tu_{t}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}\psi(1)\sum_{t=1}^T\varepsilon_t+\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}(\eta_t-\eta_0)\to N(0,[\psi(1)\sigma]^2),$$

where we apply the central limit theorem for the first term and observe that the second term goes to zero, due to stationarity (mean is zero and variance of term goes to zero, due to T in the denominator).

So we get that limiting behaviour of ARIMA(p,1,q) process is simply the same as for a ARIMA(0,1,0) process. This fact is used a lot in the time series literature. For example Phillips and Perron unit root test is based on it.

Comment: this is probably a dumb question since I do not use Cross Validate enough, but why do I see all the dollar signs and dashes? am I missing some kind of script?

Comment: So the text inside the dollar signs is not converted to formulas? CrossValidated has MathJax enabled, which means that you can use Latex code in the text, which is translated in nice looking mathematical formulas. If you do not see it, you might be using some non-standart browser setup. What browser do you use?

Comment: Ah that is what it is thank you. I am using firefox. I think the noscript addon might be blocking the feature.

Comment: Yes, mathjax is using javascript. Enable javascript on this sight to see the difference.

Comment: (+1) I was looking for a good (and short) interpretation of BND and found at last :)